# How to add style for last visible element without JS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This selector doesn't work. Is it really possible?

See this http://jsfiddle.net/Hd7VZ/

```
.x-form-fieldset:last-child:not(x-item-hidden) {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

One of solution is this http://jsfiddle.net/8Fpyu/

Comment: this is what's possible http://vogtjosh.com/selectors/ and you can't stack pseudo selectors

Comment: if you want last child inside .x-form-fieldset add space before :last-child

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Musa: I want to not display the border on last element. See example on jsfiddle in my description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by antejan is correct, currently you're selecting the `.x-form-fieldset` which is `:last-child` in its block. If you want to select the `:last-child` within `.x-form-fieldset` then this is the correct syntax:

```
.x-form-fieldset :last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

However even if the last item is hidden it is still `:last-child`, so adding the `:not` will achieve nothing in your example.

There is nothing in CSS at present which allows you to ignore non-visible elements, as you can see from [this small modification of your example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hd7VZ/1/) simple effects like alternate striping are also broken by hiding elements.  This may be a worthwhile addition to a future version of CSS, you could try [suggesting it to the W3C CSS Working Group](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/) and seeing if they think it'd be worth adding to a future version of the selectors spec ([CSS Selectors Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/) is going through the standards process right now, but [ideas are being accepted for CSS5 Selectors](http://wiki.csswg.org/spec/selectors)).

In the meantime, you're stuck with either finding an alternative markup approach, or hacking it in JavaScript.

Comment: As I am expected the one way is hacking) By the way, thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a syntax error, add a '.' if it's a class or '#' if it's an id before x-item-hidden.
`.x-form-fieldset:last-child:not(.x-item-hidden)` | `.x-form-fieldset:last-child:not(#x-item-hidden)`